# Problema al subir dos imágenes con Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

Estoy tratando de subir en un mismo formulario dos imágenes, una me la trata como imagen, pero otra no entiendo porqué lo trata como un string a la hora de llegar al controller. Dejo a continuación todo el código que veo necesario:

En el controlador:

```
 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        /** @var UploadedFile $file */
        $file = $client->getPic();
        dump($file);
        if ($file == null) {
            $client->setPic($lastFile);
        } else {
            // Generate a unique name for the file before saving it
            $fileName = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

            // Move the file to the directory where brochures are stored
            $file->move(
                $this->getParameter('pics_directory'),
                $fileName
            );

            $client->setPic($fileName);
        }

        $lastFile = $client->getLogo();
        /** @var UploadedFile $file */
        $file = $client->getLogo();
        dump($file);
        if ($file == null) {
            $client->setLogo($lastFile);
        } else {
            // Generate a unique name for the file before saving it
            $fileName = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

            // Move the file to the directory where brochures are stored
            $file->move(
                $this->getParameter('pics_directory'),
                $fileName
            );


            $client->setLogo($fileName);
        }
        $em->flush();
```

En el dump el primero sale como un objeto file y el segundo como un simple string:

> In ClientController.php line 90:
>
> UploadedFile {#37 ▼
>     -test: false
>     -originalName: "menos.png"
>     -mimeType: "image/png"
>     -size: 2569
>     -error: 0
>     path: "/tmp"
>     filename: "phpYzHDK3"
>     basename: "phpYzHDK3"
>     pathname: "/tmp/phpYzHDK3"
>     extension: ""
>     realPath: "/tmp/phpYzHDK3"
>     aTime: 2017-09-25 09:47:13
>     mTime: 2017-09-25 09:47:13
>     cTime: 2017-09-25 09:47:13
>     inode: 18618722
>     size: 2569
>     perms: 0100600
>     owner: 1000
>     group: 1000
>     type: "file"
>     writable: true
>     readable: true
>     executable: false
>     file: true
>     dir: false
>     link: false
>   }
>
> In ClientController.php line 109:
>
> "/tmp/php5iX8qq"

Obviamente, el error que me muestra es que el segundo file es un string:

> Call to a member function guessExtension() on string

Dejo el código también del entity y del type. que por cierto son idénticos:

Entity:

```
 /**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={"image/png"})
 */
private $pic;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={"image/png"})
 */

private $logo;
/**
  * @return string
 */
 public function getPic()
{
    return $this->pic;
}

/**
 * @param string $pic
 * @return Client
 */
public function setPic($pic)
{
    $this->pic = $pic;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getLogo()
{
    return $this->logo;
}

/**
 * @param string $logo
 * @return Client
 */
public function setLogo(string $logo)
{
    $this->logo = $logo;
    return $this;
}
```

Type:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('pic', FileType::class, [
            'data_class' => null,
            'required' => false
        ])
        ->add('logo', FileType::class, [
        'data_class' => null,
        'required' => false
    ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Client::class
    ]);
}
```

Comment: ¿Es necesario poner un solo campo para las dos imágenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has probado a usar una variable diferente para cada archivo?

```
$filePic = $client->getPic();
$fileLogo = $client->getLogo();
```